# htaccess rewrite from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently I redirect all http users (www or non-www) of [upscfever.com](http://upscfever.com) to http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/index.html

using

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^upscfever\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.upscfever\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/upscfever\.com\/upsc\-fever\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Now I want all users to shift to https so I modified as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^upscfever\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.upscfever\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/upscfever\.com\/upsc\-fever\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

So that all who type upscfever.com OR www.upscfever.com should go to
https://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/index.html - instead

Plus all links should be https. But its not working I get Page not found.

Comment: Just my curios, why you done let a tool like cerbot redirec all you request to https instead add an .htaccess file ? Some config like this `root /var/www/upscfever.com/upsc-fever;`

Answer (score 0):

Your server has to setup the https first, depend on hosting vendor, if your hosting is vps you need to setup https for apache, install cert also.

You can find some instruction like this:

https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_apache.html

https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make 3 different changes:

1. Change your .htaccess file to redirect requests to root to your custom index irrespective of the HTTPS or HTTP for the original request

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^upscfever\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.upscfever\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://%{SERVER_NAME}/upsc-fever/index.html" [R,L]
```

There is no `R=301` part here because I'm not sure it is really wise to make permanent such a redirect to an obscure inner URL.

2. Redirect all other non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS (preserving the rest of the URL):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^upscfever\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.upscfever\.com$

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Making this redirect permanent seems pretty safe.

3. Change all ***internal*** links in all of your HTML pages (or whatever backend generates them) to use protocol-relative `//` prefix or explicitly `https://` instead of current `http://`. Preserve the protocol for the external links as is.

As for troubleshooting, you may use the Network tab of the Chrome DevTools (F12) to see exact server reply (note: enabling "Preserve log" and "Disable cache" flags is useful in such context)

[image: Chrome DevTools]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a single rule as follows in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?upscfever\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /upsc-fever/index.html [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect both `http` and `https` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will do the work for you

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://famebooking.net/$1 [R,L]
```

just simply add above code in .htaccess below `authorization header condition` is written under `RewriteEngine On`

Let me know if that helps.